# How to save images from camera using Gdi+

Tags: visual-c++, gdi+

I'm wanted to know how to read the stream from camera directly and write/save the same to the computer. I'm using Visual studio 2012 with an external camera.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of connection do you have to the camera?

Comment: @user2867342 camera is connected via USB and I have installed the drivers for that external camera

Comment: If the camera comes with an API library, then use than. Otherwise you'll be trying to talk to the USB driver without any information on how it works.

Comment: @varsha_holla Let men know what solution do you used?

Comment: @RezaAghaei I don't know what to use. I'm just trying out with the WIA as mentioned in the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630368(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) is the still image acquisition
>   platform in the Windows family of operating systems starting with
>   Windows Millennium Edition (Windows Me) and Windows XP.
>
> The WIA platform enables imaging/graphics applications to interact
>   with imaging hardware and standardizes the interaction between
>   different applications and scanners. This allows those different
>   applications to talk to and interact with those different scanners
>   without requiring the application writers and scanner manufactures to
>   customize their application or drivers for each application-device
>   combination.

Here is a sample from code Project:

- [WebCam Fast Image Capture Service using WIA](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15219/WebCam-Fast-Image-Capture-Service-using-WIA)